# armazenamento de int em c

Tags: c

Estou iniciando em C e fazendo um programa que registra algumas informacoes (todas essas informacoes vao para um arquivo). cada registro tem um número de registro, começando pelo registro 0001. O problema é que estou tentando armazenar o número do ultimo registro feito em outro arquivo, para saber qual será o proximo número de registro para que a cada vez que eu registrar uma reclamacao o numero_reclamacao dela seja o da numero_reclamacao anterior + 1
link pro codigo completo http://dontpad.com/codigoint

```
FILE *total;
numero_reclamacao = 1;
total = fopen("total.txt", "a+b");

            if(total){
                while(!feof(total)){
                    fscanf(total , "%d", &numero_reclamacao);//lendo o ultimo
                }                                            //n de reclamacao
            }
            else{
                printf("ERRO");
            }

numero_reclamacao += 1;//incrementando + 1           

registrar(numero_reclamacao,outros parametros);//funcao que registra

fprintf(total, "%d", numero_reclamacao);//escrevendo no arquivo o último n de 
                                         //reclamacao usado

fclose(total);
```

o que está acontecendo é que sempre que registro uma reclamacao o número dela é 1, nunca vai para 2, 3, 4, etc

Comment: Se é um arquivo texto por que você especifica binário (opção b) no fopen?

Comment: foi só pra testar, mas com ou sem o b eu tenho o mesmo problema

Comment: primeira coisa: corrija a indentação do código...com indentação descuidada fica mais difícil de entender...além disso o código está incompleto...não que seja para colocar 500 linhas, mas pelo menos a funcão completa, e/ou a função main completa iria ajudar mais o entendimento

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo do arquivo após pelo menos uma execução?

Comment: link para código completo http://dontpad.com/codigoint

Comment: o conteúdo do arquivo era pra ser 1 na primeira execução, 2 na segunda, 3 na terceira, etc

Comment: Não perguntei o que era para ser mas sim o real conteúdo do arquivo após algumas execuções.

Comment: fica sempre o que estava já lá, se eu colocar 10, sempre vai registrar a reclamacao 10 e nunca vai gravar 11 no arquivo, se nao tiver nada no arquivo fica sempre 0, nunca incrementa

Answer (score 0):

Se o fscanf estiver sendo executado, então o conteúdo do arquivo onde você guarda o último registro está em branco ou não está sendo lido adequadamente... e o fscanf acaba escrevendo o valor 0 na variável. 
Por conta disso, a variável sempre assume o valor 1 após o incremento.